# How to duplicate a range of cell with the same format?

Tags: excel, vba

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEoae.png)

Okay, so I'm a big starter in VBA and created a sheet for that will be the base for every proposition… So I protected the file and locked some cells. Now when can someone help me find a way to execute my VBA code without unprotected the cells?

```
Sub AddRowAndFormat()
Range("A14:I14").Copy
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This Module help me to insert the same line every time I want to extend the proposition.

Comment: Apply the protection using `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`.

Comment: Sub AddRowAndFormat()
UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Range("A14:I14").Copy
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Comment: I need to write it like that ?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Protection.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I finally did it ! It will change my collaborators' life, thank you again !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code, upgraded:

```
Sub AddRowAndFormat()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Proposition de contrat")
     ws.Unprotect Password:=792432700
       Range("A14:K14").Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
     ws.Protect Password:=792432700, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
        AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
       

End Sub
```

I had to define the worksheet and `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`...